# Only display 1 article in RSS feed YUI

Tags: javascript, rss, yui

I only want to display one article but when I change the (0,2) to (0,1) nothing appears. Is there a quick solution?

```js
YUI().use('yql', function(Y){
    var query = 'select * from rss(0,2) where url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/money_latest.rss"'
    var q = Y.YQL(query, function(r){
        //r now contains the result of the YQL Query as a JSON
        var feedmarkup = '<div>'
        var feed = r.query.results.item // get feed as array of entries
        for (var i=0; i<feed.length; i++){
            feedmarkup += '<p><a href="' + feed[i].link + '">'
            feedmarkup += feed[i].title + '</a></p>'
            feedmarkup += '<p>' + feed[i].description + '</p>' 
   feedmarkup += '<p><a href="' + feed[i].link + '">'
            feedmarkup += '<span class="more">Read more</span>' + '</a></p>'  
        }  
        document.getElementById('uknews').innerHTML = feedmarkup
    })
})
```

```html
  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
  <div id="uknews"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and hope this helps someone else:

```js
YUI().use('yql', function(Y) {

  var query = 'select * from rss(0,1) where url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss"'
  var q = Y.YQL(query, function(r) {
    //r now contains the result of the YQL Query as a JSON
    var feedmarkup = '<div class="news-feed">'
    var feed = r.query.count > 1 ? r.query.results.item : [r.query.results.item]; // get feed as array of entries
    for (var i = 0; i < feed.length; i++) {
      feedmarkup += '<div class="feed-title"><a href="' + feed[i].link + '">'
      feedmarkup += feed[i].title + '</a></div>'
      feedmarkup += '<div class="feed-description">' + feed[i].description + '</div>'
      feedmarkup += '<div class="feed-link"><a href="' + feed[i].link + '">'
      feedmarkup += '<span class="more">Learn more</span>' + '</a></p>'
    }

    document.getElementById('uknews').innerHTML = feedmarkup
  })
})
```

```css
.feedflare {
  display: none;
}

div.feed-description {
  display: block;
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

<div id="uknews"></div>
```